# Express -access application without port

Tags: node.js, express

With expressjs, how to access application without port, default port for expressjs is 3000 but we have to access the application without port.
Do we need install any webserver like and expose this with it?

Comment: If you want with out Port, You have run the application in 80 Port instead of 3000 if HTTP. If you have HTTPS then run on 443.

Comment: You can access your application without port, If you are using default HTTP ( 80) or HTTPS (443) port for your server, If you want to run without external proxy server then you will have to run your node process as root/administrator else you can use nginx/apache to proxy 80 to your server running on 3000 port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All http requests are made on some port.  A browser URL without a port in the URL uses:

```
port 80 - for http
port 443 - for https
```

So, if you want a server for http without a port specified in the URL, you have to have an http server running port 80.  Likewise if you want a server for https withotu a port specified in the URL, you have to have an https server running on port 443.

If your http server is running on port 3000, then you will have to put that in the URL as in:

```
http://somedomain.com:3000/index.html
```

---

You don't say what type of hosting system you are running on, but many hosting facilities provide some sort of proxy that you can configure for your domain that will forward port 80 requests sent to your domain to your port xxxx server running in their facility.  How you configure that depends upon the hosting service you are using.  The hosting facility doesn't let you run directly on port 80 because they may be running multiple servers on the same hardware who can't all use port 80.  So, they use a proxy to direct multiple different domains, all running on port 80 to separate ports in the hosting facility (invisible to the client side who think they're just talking to a server on port 80).